# gnuplot Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, gnuplot, apt-get

Trying to install gnuplot with `sudo apt-get install gnuplot` threw the following error:

> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Ditto via the Ubuntu Software Centre. Calling `sudo apt-get install -f` leads to no progress. As I try to install the first unmet dependencies manually, the problem branches off with further unmet dependencies far too quickly.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the gnuplot 4.4.3 is the candidate for installation.

Could someone remind me of the best way to manage this problem and install the intended package truly automatically? Guidance even in pseudo-form appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `apt-get update` first.   If no help, post your apt sources configuration (i.e. sources.list and sources.d/*).

Comment: FWIW there is also http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Something is out of date badly, because Ubuntu Trusty should be providing you with gnuplot 4.6 (which is still out of date).  Additionally, that package is not going to supply you with an interactive terminal.  Try installing `gnuplot-qt` or `gnuplot-x11` for an interactive terminal, or `gnuplot-nox` if you don't need one.  Do what @JamesYoungman recommended first and note that you will need to run that command with sudo.

Comment: @JamesYoungman Done update with sudo, to no avail. Is there a repository where I can post and link the requested files? @Matthew `gnuplot-qt` is not even located by apt-get, while `gnuplot-x11` throws the same error as `gnuplot` whence back to square one.

Comment: You could use www.pastebin.com.